# intel corporation: Dual Band Wireless-AC3168NGW [stone peak] wifi not working on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have installed ubuntu 20.04LTS. My laptop is HP probook 645 g4, amd ryzen7. Intel wireless ac3168NGW is used in this laptop to use wifi. After installing Ubuntu, the 'Additional Drivers' in the Software & update, it is showing that intel corporation: Dual Band Wireless-AC3168NGW [stone peak]-this device is not working. and give me an option to contine using a manually installed driver.
I have tried 2 common solutions. The wifi comes and suddenly gets disconnected. After getting disconnected, in the wifi section in the system setting, it is showing that the wifi adapter is not found. and the wifi on-off button is gone away. It's really a pain. I have given the 2 solutions below. These do not work perfectly. if anyone gives me a perfect solution,

my-try-1:

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0
sudo cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

my-try-2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

and.. I am not using any dual boot. I have installed ubuntu whole my hard drive. "dmesg | grep iwl" result below.

```
santo@santo-HP-ProBook-645-G4:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    8.185397] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.529421] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.531171] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    9.741272] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
[    9.764147] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: f4:d1:08:30:92:29
[    9.794546] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    9.800278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  124.117970] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[  124.118166] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  124.118350] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  124.118354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  124.118356] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
[  124.118360] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  124.118362] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000230 | trm_hw_status0
[  124.118364] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  124.118366] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D6C | branchlink2
[  124.118368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink1
[  124.118370] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000008A0 | interruptlink2
[  124.118372] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  124.118374] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  124.118375] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  124.118377] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x63802E09 | beacon time
[  124.118379] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB33781F6 | tsf low
[  124.118381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  124.118382] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  124.118384] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x05F0D44C | time gp2
[  124.118386] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  124.118388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  124.118389] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[  124.118391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  124.118393] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  124.118395] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[  124.118396] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x24022002 | isr0
[  124.118398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00800000 | isr1
[  124.118400] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  124.118402] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00417CC0 | isr3
[  124.118403] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  124.118405] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00F1014E | last cmd Id
[  124.118407] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  124.118408] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  124.118410] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00010030 | l2p_duration
[  124.118412] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  124.118414] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[  124.118415] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  124.118417] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[  124.118419] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0034B0C0 | flow_handler
[  124.118530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  124.118579] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  124.118624] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  124.118670] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  124.118717] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  124.118763] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  124.118809] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  124.118855] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  124.118902] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  124.118948] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  124.118995] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  124.119041] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  124.119086] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  124.119140] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[  144.592938] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[  144.593260] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  144.593493] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  144.593497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  144.593501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
[  144.593505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  144.593508] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002F3 | trm_hw_status0
[  144.593511] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  144.593513] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D6C | branchlink2
[  144.593516] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink1
[  144.593519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000066FC | interruptlink2
[  144.593521] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  144.593524] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  144.593526] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x03030000 | data3
[  144.593529] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x89005E5D | beacon time
[  144.593531] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB47035A2 | tsf low
[  144.593534] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  144.593536] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  144.593538] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0135685A | time gp2
[  144.593541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  144.593543] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  144.593546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[  144.593548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  144.593550] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  144.593552] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[  144.593555] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x02F62000 | isr0
[  144.593557] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x01004000 | isr1
[  144.593559] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  144.593561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00417C80 | isr3
[  144.593563] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  144.593566] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0B80001C | last cmd Id
[  144.593568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  144.593570] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  144.593572] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00001C22 | l2p_duration
[  144.593574] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  144.593576] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[  144.593579] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  144.593581] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[  144.593583] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0034C8D8 | flow_handler
[  144.593695] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  144.593741] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  144.593787] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  144.593833] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  144.593881] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  144.593928] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  144.593974] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  144.594022] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  144.594067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  144.594114] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  144.594161] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  144.594207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  144.594254] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  144.594308] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[  165.042760] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[  165.042955] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  165.043201] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  165.043204] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  165.043207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
[  165.043211] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  165.043214] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002B0 | trm_hw_status0
[  165.043216] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  165.043219] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D6C | branchlink2
[  165.043221] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink1
[  165.043223] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink2
[  165.043225] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  165.043227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  165.043230] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  165.043232] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x89002905 | beacon time
[  165.043234] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB5A886FA | tsf low
[  165.043235] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  165.043237] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  165.043239] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0134F25F | time gp2
[  165.043241] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  165.043243] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  165.043245] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[  165.043246] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  165.043248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  165.043250] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[  165.043252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00022002 | isr0
[  165.043254] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  165.043255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  165.043257] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00417CC0 | isr3
[  165.043259] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  165.043261] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0B8F001C | last cmd Id
[  165.043263] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  165.043264] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  165.043266] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00010020 | l2p_duration
[  165.043268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  165.043270] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[  165.043272] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000005 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  165.043273] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[  165.043275] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0034C8D0 | flow_handler
[  165.043387] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  165.043434] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  165.043481] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  165.043527] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  165.043574] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  165.043620] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  165.043666] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  165.043712] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  165.043758] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  165.043804] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  165.043851] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  165.043898] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  165.043944] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  165.043996] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[  185.501784] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: regular scan timed out
[  185.502006] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  185.502248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  185.502251] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  185.502254] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
[  185.502258] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  185.502261] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002A0 | trm_hw_status0
[  185.502263] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  185.502266] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D6C | branchlink2
[  185.502268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink1
[  185.502270] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink2
[  185.502272] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  185.502274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  185.502277] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  185.502279] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x86803393 | beacon time
[  185.502281] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB6E0FC6B | tsf low
[  185.502283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  185.502285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  185.502287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x013539A4 | time gp2
[  185.502289] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  185.502291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  185.502294] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[  185.502296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  185.502298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  185.502300] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[  185.502302] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00022002 | isr0
[  185.502304] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  185.502306] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[  185.502308] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0041C4C0 | isr3
[  185.502310] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  185.502312] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x863F009D | last cmd Id
[  185.502315] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  185.502317] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
[  185.502319] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00018020 | l2p_duration
[  185.502321] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
[  185.502323] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000081 | l2p_addr_match
[  185.502325] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000005 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  185.502327] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[  185.502329] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0034C8E0 | flow_handler
[  185.502442] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  185.502488] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  185.502535] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  185.502581] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  185.502629] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  185.502676] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  185.502723] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  185.502768] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  185.502814] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  185.502860] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  185.502907] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  185.502953] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  185.502999] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  185.503054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Is this a dual boot with Windows? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: edited. Please check. it is not dual boot with windows. I have installed ubuntu whole my hard drive

Answer (score 0):

In your edit, we see many repetitions of:

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000. 
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
```

There is a very long bug report about firmware crashes and the Intel 3168: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204151 It suggests that the issue is fixed in kernel version 5.5 and later. I believe that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses kernel version 5.4.

I suggest that you download the iso for Ubuntu 20.10 which currently uses kernel version 5.8. Next, try a live session, also known as “Try Ubuntu.”

Does your wireless work as expected? Are there any clues in the message log?

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Do all other functions; that is email, web browser, etc. work as expected? If so, I suggest that you install it.

**EDIT**: Please check the integrity of the firmware file:

```
md5sum /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
```

We hope you see: 35ba5d5a8bdd6ff453106d268eda957e

If not, please do:

```
sudo apt install –reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Any improvement?

If not, rename the -29 version so that the system instead loads -27:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/
sudo mv iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode  iwlwifi-3168-29.bak
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement? If not, revert the change and reboot:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/
sudo mv iwlwifi-3168-29.bak  iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
```

Comment: Note, Ubuntu 20.04.2 ISO is available and uses HWE kernel 5.8, the same as Ubuntu 20.10. One should be able to stay in LTS and get the kernel version 5.8.

Comment: The one which I installed on my laptop is ubuntu 20.10. The kernel version is 5.8. And the bug is not fixed maybe. because the wifi issue is not solved yet on my laptop.

Comment: "I have installed ubuntu 20.04LTS" Hence my confusion. Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: the problem didn't solve yet. Maybe this issue is a major issue and ubuntu should fix it.

Comment: As Intel supplies the hardware, the driver *and* the firmware, I'm not sure Ubuntu can do much about it. I suggest that you start here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu