# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC3168NGW has a very slow speed

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi

I bought an MSI B550M PRO VDH WIFI motherboard and I installed an Ubuntu 22.04 distribution on it.
Everything works fine, except WIFI which has a very slow speed.
I have tried to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322645/intel-corporation-dual-band-wireless-ac3168ngw-stone-peak-wifi-not-working-on), but it didn't work for me.

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    6.978615] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.979005] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.979436] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3168-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.983328] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: loaded firmware version 27.541033.0 3168-27.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.097725] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
[    7.115641] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: base HW address: 7c:50:79:2e:c3:0e
[    7.145564] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.147387] iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0 wlp41s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I would like to know if this issue has a solution or not. And if it hasn't, does a USB Wi-Fi adapter is a good idea to use instead of the built-in Wi-Fi.

Comment: Please check my trouleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: @chili555 we have different issue,  I have connection,  but it is very slow. It doesn't reach the speed that I have in other devices.

Comment: Many of the techniques also help with speed, especially seperating the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments as well as fixed channel and WPA2 and never TKIP.

Comment: @chili555 Now it is worst than before. Before it did not drop, now it keeps dropping and has a very very poor wifi speed.

Comment: What did you change? May we see, in an edit: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact the MAC addresses with xxxx.